# Orders of the elements in $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I know that the order of an element $a$ in a group is the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $a^n = 1$.

> You know $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z} = \{\overline{0}, \overline{1}, \dotsc, \overline{7}\}$. Write down the orders of each of the $8$ elements.

So for lets say order of an element $0$ in the group $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$, the order is infinite right since there are no $n$ that satisfy the equation? What about the other $7$ elements, should I consider mod with each element?

Thank you

Comment: the order of $\bar{0}$ is $1$, not infinite.

Comment: You're confusing additive and multiplicative notation I suspect. The neutral element here is $0$ not $1$.

Comment: In an additive group, the identity (usually denoted as $1$ in a multiplicative group) is denoted by $0$.

Comment: I guess the confusion is because in your question you are writting the identity as 0, while you are writing the order equation as $a^n = 1$. If 0 is your symbol of identity then the this should be $a^n = 0$.

Comment: @Hamed more precisely, it should be $na=a+a+\dots+a=0$. We don't want to mix additive and multiplicative notation.

Comment: Exactly, good point.

Comment: I got it, was confusing additive and multiplicative notation. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As been pointed out you confuse the different notations. As for the elements
$$0*0=0$$
$$8*1=0$$
$$4*2=0$$
$$8*3=0$$
$$2*4=0$$
$$8*5=0$$
$$4*6=0$$
$$8*7=0$$